# How can I add a texture with an alpha channel without affecting the base materials opacity?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, node-editor

I'm trying to make this handle look dirty by using a texture with an alpha channel. It's actually adding some transparency to the base material which I want to look solid.

I have tried changing the order of where I plug nodes into the sockets which only makes it worse.

Render
[image: Render]
Seeing back edges
[image: Problem]
Nodes
[image: Nodes]
Texture
[image: Texture]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are so close!

Delete the transparency node and make suitable adjustments.

[image]

- Above the nodes overlay color.
- The nodes select color by alpha channel.
- There is no desired transparency in the final material.
- There is no need for any transparent shader.
- Selecting color and final material transparency are different.